# Morris.js create other display label for values

Tags: for-loop, charts, label, morris.js

I want to use Morris.js but I have a problem.

I want to use the bar chart to do a comparison between two weeks.
I want to compare two times in two different days.

For example:

This Day: 10:03
Last Day: 3:34

I can convert the hours in minutes so I have a integer, but my bar chart is also in minutes then. Can you help me so I can use the minutes for the calculation of the bars but my Labels and my chart should show 10:03 instead of 603.

Sorry for my bad English, that's the reason why I ask here. I'm not able to google that because I have absolutely no idea how I should google this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hoverCallback` to achieve what you want.

I iterated over the `ykeys`, getting the hours and minutes with 2 digits (adding a 0 if needed), then replacing the current integer value `row[v]` in `hours:minutes` format.

Please try the following snippet:

```js
new Morris.Bar({
    element: 'chart',
    data: [
      { t: "Week1", a: 63, b: 105 },
      { t: "Week2", a: 33, b: 247 }
    ],
    xkey: 't',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    labels: ['This Day', 'Last Day'],
    stacked: false,
    hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
        var finalContent = content;

        $.each(options.ykeys, function (i, v) {
            var hours = ("0" + Math.floor(row[v] / 60)).slice(-2);
            var minutes = ("0" + row[v] % 60).slice(-2);
            finalContent = finalContent.replace(row[v], hours + ":" + minutes);
        });

        return finalContent;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread but is there a way to display an alternate string. For example if my value is below 0 instead of showing the Y value I want to show a string. I also am using your other code to change the colour of the dot on the graph if it is below 0.

Comment: @Tarquin Yes you can display whatever you want in the `hoverCallback`. You can create a new question if you want more details.

Comment: Sure thing, I juste hate risking it because many of the mods here flag it as duplicate or too-specific to be useful to the wider community. I'll come back here once I have posted it.